# code for counting number of hits in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count, view, hit

i want to know the code for counting number of hits in my ruby on rails application : conditions are it should not increment when a refresh action is executed. And it should be incremented by 1 only when clicked by a unique MAC address

Comment: No of hits or Number of views. that is no of times the application has been viewed by unique mac address users ! :-)

Comment: Please help ! i tried searching but didnt get any !

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283185/retrieving-client-system-information-from-a-rails-application its not possible it think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it is possible to get mac ids

[Retrieving client system information from a Rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283185/retrieving-client-system-information-from-a-rails-application)

Try some analytics to get unique visitors details.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done using Rails Application, but you can do this using [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/).

This will give more detailed statistical information based on Host IP, Country, Browsers, etc,.